# What's the best way of creating documents with embedded objects?

Tags: emacs, database, libreoffice, latex, documents

I'm looking for a way of creating documents that allow me to embed multiple things.

So far I'm aware of:

- Libre Office .odt
- Emacs orgmode .org
- LaTeX .tex
- HTML file .html
- PDF file .pdf

I'm not sure if these technologies can do what I need to be able to do. Does anyone have any advice as to which of those would be most suitable? Or is there a better way to achieve the desired result?

This is what I'd like to be able to do:
[image]

Comment: The best tool is the one you know how to use. But Videos can make the compressed file rather large unless linked from web.  Libre, OO or MSO are pretty similar in function but performance may be better in MSO.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend OpenOffice.org for the videos you'll want to upload them to Youtube or Vimeo so they play back on mobile devices as well. Have you tried OpenOffice?

Comment: Isn't OpenOffice the same as LibreOffice?

Answer (score 0):

LaTeX  is capable of doing what are you seeking. You need to include packages that allow you to embed mutlimedia in your document.  For more info regarding this feature, see this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1574/embedding-videos-and-animations).